# Same Bundle ID suffix on iPad and iPhone versions of App

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, game-center, cfbundleidentifier

This is a subtle question. I am planning to release an iOS app with two versions - one for iPhone and iPod Touch, and the other for iPad. The apps will be named, say, `MyApp` and `MyApp HD`. The app allows you to save files, and also to communicate with other users of the app via GameCenter.

I would like the iPad and iPhone versions to be able to interchange files, and also to communicate with each other via GameCenter. So, my question is, in iTunesConnect, should (and can I) assign both apps the same bundle ID (e.g. `com.mycompany.myapp`) or do I have to give them different bundle IDs (e.g. `com.mycompany.myapp` and `com.mycompany.myapphd`).

iOS and GameCenter experts, please advise!

Comment: Why not create an Universal App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer I received from developer support:

Every app in the store is required to have an unique id, however, that id has common elements with other ids such as:

```
com.mycompany.myapp.ipad
com.mycompany.myapp.iphone
```

And regarding GameCenter: GameCenter has no support for sharing data between two apps. The only way for an iPad and iPhone app to share data is for there to be one universal app for both platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Each app needs a different bundle ID. You can have a single bundle ID if you create a universal app, otherwise they'll need to have different ones and will appear as different apps in GameCenter.